# Other Wordpress installation on subfolder?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I tried many forum tips to load WP in subfolder, the 2 site is working and can edit the original.com but but can´t login to original.com/en/wp-login.php

Always 404 - Page Not Found.

The webserver is LiteSpeed and the original .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# Skip your second WordPress installation
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|en/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The second site´s .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Set the RewriteBase to this directory
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Remove the slash before index.php or we end up at root
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where I making mistake?

Comment: Have you set up a virtual server: https://openlitespeed.org/kb/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting-on-openlitespeed/ ?

Comment: I use aaPanel, so have own config, no panel.